# Different ways to analyze football (soccer) teams to predict the winner in the premier league

Tags: probability

I am writing a 12-page high school paper on how to predict the winner of a football league(English Premier League). The statistics being used are goals scored home and away the previous season (I can get more variable if required)

I am not sure how to go about it since I am not understanding the way in which I can analyze the data. Should I make an attempt by using multivariable linear regression or should I use probability to determine the chances of each team winning? 
The website I have consulted is https://ibmathsresources.com/2019/06/19/simulating-a-football-season/

Thanks

Comment: It is always problematic to estimate such probabilities. This is not like coin tossing or a roulette wheel, but much more complex. If you have found a reasonable model, just use it.

Comment: If you have multiple methods, all the better!  Try all of them.  Describe where the models agree with each other and where they conflict.  In practice, that's about the best you can do.

Comment: FiveThirtyEight does something like this, but they base their predictions on a much richer data set than just the past season’s performance. You may want to look up their version of this.